# Clear Angular FormControls after save without form errors

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, form-control, formgroups

I have the following code:

```
initializeForm(): void {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('hello world', Validators.required)
    });
}

clearValues(): void {
    // save my form.. or do something, then clear my form
    this.myForm.patchValue({ name: null });
}
```

And then in my html I have the input and some button to save changes. After that I call clearValues.

```
<input type=text formControlName="name">
<button (click)="clearValues()">Save</button>
```

When I start my app, the field has no red errors so I can type everything, but If I leave it empty, red errors appears (obviously).

If I write something such as 'Hello World' and I save. The input becomes empty and the red errors appears.

I tried with **markAsTouched()** or **markAsDirty** but the same results happens.

How I can click the button and leave the input without errors?

This is what I get, I want an empty with no errors input.

[image]

Comment: your html should have a a `<form>` tag with `(submit)="clearValues()"`, while the button can be just: `<button type="submit">...`. Then it's enough to call `this.myForm.reset()` in your submit function to clear it

Comment: The error still appear because the FormControl it has "Validators.required" so when the .reset() calls, the input becomes empty and the error appears because is required.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
this.myForm.reset();
Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach(key => {
    this.myForm.controls[key].setErrors(null);
});
```

Working this way. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a function for this](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#resetform) on the form object.

```
this.myForm.resetForm();
```